# Why doesn't saved data with translates option in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, globalize

In the Rails 4.2 app I'm using globalize gem:

```
gem 'globalize', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'globalize-versioning', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'paperclip-globalize3', '~> 2.2.0'
```

I have model `Benefit` that has field with translation:

```
class Benefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  validates_presence_of :name

  # other code
end
```

Then I tried to create a new record with Rails console:

```
Benefit.create!(name: 'test_name', display_order: 1)
```

I saw next SQL query in the log:

```
INSERT INTO `benefits` (`display_order`) VALUES (1)
```

The `name` field recorded in DB with a NULL value.
When I commented out `translates` line, all data were stored in DB.
This code works good in Rails 3.2.21 (globalize3 0.3.1 and paperclip-globalize3 1.1.0).

What could be the appearance of this error?

Comment: what is your `I18n.locale` is it `:en` or anything else?

Comment: Yes, it's `:en` locale.

Comment: Have a look it here, whatever code you posted it looks good. https://github.com/globalize/globalize

Comment: have you created the translation table? see https://github.com/globalize/globalize#creating-translation-tables

Comment: I have all translation tables, because I try to update project from Rails 3.2.21 to 4.2.0.